# Acumatica Customization Packages for small teams (3 devs)

Tags: acumatica

For a team of 3 developers in an Acumatica project which uses the Acumatica Extensibility Framework (AEF) quite heavily, we are using Git as a source control. However, I am still not sure what strategy should we follow regarding creation of Customization Projects. Should we just use 1 Customization Project to be shared across all developers or should we divide Customization Projects per feature (or possibly per developer)? What are the implications of each approach? Is there any guidance by Acumatica on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do a single customization project as we are working on a single product (multiple modules). Distributing the customization makes it easier as a single zip file vs many zip files. We use a powershel script to create the customization package outside of Acumatica which simply stitches all of the files into a newly created zip file. This way each developer can quickly make a customization package and load the latest as needed (again pointing to a single package as our preferred approach). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would be nice if you could share the powershell script (not sure whether that's possible)

Comment: it is very specific to our TFS file structure. It just does a bunch of file copies, updates customization description (manipulating XML), and then creating a zip. Most of these functions can be found on stackoverflow or google and just put them all together. I prefer powershell over a .net console app just because i can quickly update the script as needed. So i could share the zip, but it might be just as easy to create from scratch without needing to figure out what we are doing with our script. Just a thought.